# How to authorize the Heroku deploy build access to a private package (Azure Artifacts)

Tags: c#, asp.net, heroku, continuous-deployment, azure-artifacts

I want to deploy a ASP.net solution on Heroku but it can't access a private package I have.

I'm using automatic deployment so that when I push changes on github in my production branch Heroku immediately tries to build and deploy the solution. For any of the other packages that are available publicly it can access them no problem. But for the one I created it does not have the credentials, even though I believe it can read the package source and package pattern no problem.
I don't want to make the package public on nuget.org, so I have it on Azure project artifacts. I need to know how to give Heroku permission to this package feed.

At first the problem was just having Heroku know where to find the package. So I had to create a nuget.config file and populate it with package patterns.
After that heroku could find the package but it couldn't access it posting the error message
"

```
Unable to parse config file because: Credentials item must have username and password. Path: '/tmp/build_60ccbe61/Web/API/nuget.config'. [/tmp/build_60ccbe61/Web/API/API.csproj]
```

"

I created a PAT ( Personal Access Token) in the Azure project with the artifacts. Cause I figured that this might help when there isn't an obvious way forward.

I then tried google and most of the solutions involve private git repositories and npm or node.js and they use a .npmrc config file.
Within my own nuget.config file I have;

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
        <MySourceName>
            <add key="Username" value="Heroku" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%HerokuPersonalAccessToken%" />
        </MySourceName>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

Which is the credentials I believe Heroku should use to access the artifact.

Now after all that, the error I get when deployed and being built by Heroku is :
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mysource/v3/index.json

Comment: Hi, if possible, could you please share the nuget.config file? Have you define the <packageSources> section? Since you use <MySourceName>, MySourceName must be defined in that part. And feed settings have permission settings, what the identity you are based on? the user who generate the personal access token? If so, does the user has required access permission to the feed?

Comment: Here is the nuget.config file I use within the solution https://filedropper.com/d/s/ivJiToho9j4omvEhGwdSPZgRVu2ZCM . 
Within the feed settings it shows the owner (me) and some project collaborators. But I'll admit I'm not sure how to add Heroku to this list, ( a bit out of depth here).
So all I did was make a PAT and hoped that that would be enough.

Please do give some kind of a walk through for this stage of adding access